# Avoiding SIGINT for pthread instances

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I'm creating threads in an infinite loop after a blocking function call.

my SIGINT handler like this below

```
get all child thread id's from pipe and kill them
close pipes, unlink named pipes
```

I want to avoid SIGINT signal for all threads except main thread. How can i do that?